# Items appeared on multiple pages on pagination. Laravel 5.1.46

Tags: laravel, pagination

```
    $this->data['items'] = $this->data['items']->orderBy($this->data['orderBy'], $this->data['order'])->simplePaginate(50);
```

Items that are already listed on the first page appeared on the second page too

Comment: what is query string, is it like ?page=2

Comment: yes, it is the default pagination I have used.

Comment: have you tested ->paginate(50);

Comment: Solved. the issue was with orderBy().